# Display random images with different origin with image/next

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, config

I'm developing a simple news aggregator website with nextjs.
I need to add the domains in next.config file to use the Image component, but the images' url are completely random.
Is there any chance to use the  component or do I have to work with the basic  tag?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could either upload all images to some cloud storage before displaying them, or proxy image requests via an internal Next API route like this:

```
// pages/api/image_proxy.ts
// Remove all type definitions if you don't use TypeScript
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { source } = req.query;

  if (!source || typeof source !== "string") {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Missing image source in request-query" });
  }
  const rStream = (await fetch(decodeURIComponent(source)).then(
    (resp) => resp.body
  )) as NodeJS.ReadableStream;

  if (!rStream) {
    /* Failed to fetch
     We could either redirect to the source URL (or some other 
    fallback url e.g. res.redirect(https://example.com/someImage.png)
    or error: */
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }

  const pt = new Stream.PassThrough();

  stream.pipeline(rStream, pt, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  });

  pt.pipe(res);
}
```

now just proxy all url sources through the route:

```
  <Image
      src={`/api/image_proxy?source=${encodeURIComponent(YOUR_IMAGE_SRC_URL)}`}
   />
```